# Nginx redirect all the incomming request base on the location block

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy. I assume I have a domain like test.com and a location block with a path like /test. the location would proxy_pass to another website like http://test2.com. when I type the URL on the browser, it redirects the first request to the application (http://test.com/test/ --> http://test2.com/). However, All the incoming requests would be sent without the location which I did not define on Nginx. How can I make all the incoming requests follow that path?
I want something like this:

- first request: http://test.com/test/ --> http://test.com
- incoming requests: http://test.com/test/statifile.js
- http://test.com/test/api/something and so on...

  ```
  server {
   listen 80;
   charset utf-8;
   server_name test.com;
   location = /auth/test{
       internal;
       proxy_pass http://test.com/test/decisions/;
       proxy_pass_request_body off;
       proxy_set_header Content-Length '';
       proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
   }
   location = /test/decisions/ {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
       proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
       proxy_pass http://valid.domain/test/api/authorization;
   }
   location /test/ {
       auth_request /auth/test;
       auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
       proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
       proxy_pass https://test2.com/;
       proxy_pass_header Server;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_redirect default;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       client_max_body_size 10240M;
   }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "incoming request" is confusing here. I assume you meant:

1. Browser makes request to `http://example.com/test/`, which is proxied by nginx to `http://2.example.com/`.
2. Browser makes subsequent request to `http://2.example.com/statfile.js` directly, when you want the requests to be made to `http://example.com/test/statfile.js`

With this problem statement, the optimal solution is to modify `2.example.com` server configuration so that it creates URLs that point to `example.com/test` instead of URLs that point to `2.example.com`. Most often there is a root URL setting in the web application that can be modified.

Less reliable and worse performance option is to use `sub_filter` module to replace all occurences of `2.example.com` with `example.com/test/` in the `proxy_pass` block.

However, this can have unintended side-effects.

Comment: I believe you are right. Thank you so much.